# How can I reuse result from JQuery for javascript textual matching?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace, string-matching

I have html elements coming into function as string, then I am injecting elements into it as string however to my surprise it didn't work.

something like:

```
var replacement = $(row).find('td:last').append("<script type=\"text/javascript\"> function remove" + override.SessionKey + "(){ $('tr[session-key=\"" + override.SessionKey + "\"]').remove(); }</script><input type=\"button\" value = \"Remove\" onClick=\"remove" + override.SessionKey + "()\" />")

row.replace($(row).find('td:last')[0],replacement[0])
```

After some further investigation I have narrowed it down to matching failing in `replace` function, basically after you search with JQuery result cannot be used for textual matching

Here is an example of what I mean:

```js
var r = "<tr class=\"hide\" session-key=\"SessionProductDataMotorEnrichmentSagaFactorScore\" session-key-data-type=\"Decimal\"><td id=\"tdDisplayName91\">SagaFactorScore</td><td id=\"tdValue91\"></td></tr>"

$('div').text(r.indexOf($(r).find('td:last')[0]));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

One would expect to always have a match as I am using contents of original html string.

**How can I reuse result from JQuery for textual matching?**

Comment: Doesn't `jQuery.find()` return a jQuery object containing `HTMLElement` objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `.outerHTML`:

```js
var r = "<tr class=\"hide\" session-key=\"SessionProductDataMotorEnrichmentSagaFactorScore\" session-key-data-type=\"Decimal\"><td id=\"tdDisplayName91\">SagaFactorScore</td><td id=\"tdValue91\"></td></tr>"

$('div').text(r.indexOf($(r).find('td:last')[0].outerHTML));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a terrible way of doing what you're trying to do.

```
var btn = $("<button></button>");
btn.attr("type","button").text("Remove").on("click",function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    tr.remove();
});
```

This creates the button with associated event bound directly to it. You can then append it to all rows, for instance, like so:

```
$("tr>td:last-child").append(function() {return btn.clone(true);});
```

Comment: Example I chose is a bit silly I suppose :) there are more exciting things happening. I completely agree with you. Problem is that generated decorated etc. thing cannot end up on a screen incomplete....